# Neo4j LIKE operator index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Does the new 'LIKE' operator of Cypher uses Lucene search engine? If not, does it uses indices at all?
I'm using neo4j version 2.3 M2

Answer (score 3):

It's to be included in the next milestone release, which is due in the next few weeks, 2.3-RC1.

The first capability will be index supported prefix search with LIKE.

Comment: Thank @Michael, so currently the regex has better performance for %term% query? Does regex use index btw?

Comment: Regex searches don't use indexes.